# Pythonic way to design class which has default data members which can be overridden by kwargs

Tags: python, class, oop, initialization, init

I think the title gives the general idea of what I am looking for, but to be more specific I will give an example with code.

So let's say I have a Python class with a few required position variables that also takes an arbitrary number of keyword arguments. The class has many data members, and some of them will be defined by the required position variables, but most are keyword argument variables where the program has default values for these variables, but if the user uses a keyword argument this will override the defaults. I am looking for the most "pythonic" way to initialize a class of this type. I have two ideas for how to do this, but each of them feels unsatisfying and like there is a more pythonic way I am missing.

```
#First Option
class SampleOne:
    def __init__(pos1, pos2, **kwargs):
        def do_defaults():
            self.kwarg1 = default_kwarg1
            self.kwarg2 = default_kwarg2
            self.kwarg3 = default_kwarg3

        def do_given():
            for variable, value in kwargs.items():
                self.variable = value
        
        self.pos1 = pos1
        self.pos2 = pos2
        do_defaults()
        do_given()
```

Or

```
#Second Option
class SampleTwo:
    def __init__(pos1, pos2, **kwargs):
        self.pos1 = pos1
        self.pos2 = pos2
        self.kwarg1 = kwargs[kwarg1] if kwarg1 in kwargs else default_kwarg1
        self.kwarg2 = kwargs[kwarg2] if kwarg2 in kwargs else default_kwarg2
        self.kwarg3 = kwargs[kwarg3] if kwarg3 in kwargs else default_kwarg3
```

I don't love the first option because it seems wasteful to set a bunch of default data members if a bunch are going to be changed, especially if there are many data members.

I don't love the second option because it looks unnecessarily busy and less readable in my opinion - I like the separation of the default values from the user-defined values and think it will make my code easier to read and change.

Also, I am using **kwargs instead of keyword arguments with default values because I am still in the early phase of the development of this codebase so the member variables needed are subject to change, but also because there is going to be a lot of member variables and it will make the function signature very ugly to have all of those parameters.

Apologies if my question is a bit long-winded, this is one of my first times asking questions on StackOverflow and I wanted to make sure I gave enough detail.

Also if it makes a difference my code needs to work in Python 3.8 and later.

Comment: Well for starters, `do_given` *doesn't work*. You'd want to use `setattr(self, variable, value)`, although, you can just do `self.__dict__.update(kwargs)` in `__init__`

Comment: " it seems wasteful to set a bunch of default data members if a bunch are going to be changed, especially if there are many data members." Wasteful in what way? Do you expect to be instantiating many, many objects? Honestly, I doubt this will be a performance hit

Comment: The first option is overly complex and unreadable, both options make it unclear what arguments your class actually accepts - your class should be as explicit as possible about the arguments it accepts. If the parameters change too often it's a sign the class, and it's scope, is poorly defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the defaults you want to support and take arbitrary ones that don't require a default. This keeps your classes readable and the implementation (relatively) clear:

```py
class Sample:
    def __init__(
        self, 
        pos1, 
        pos2, 
        kwarg1='default_1', 
        kwarg2='default_2', 
        kwarg3='default_3', 
        **kwargs
    ):
        self.pos1 = pos1
        self.pos2 = pos2
        self.kwarg1 = kwarg1
        self.kwarg2 = kwarg2
        self.kwarg3 = kwarg3

        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but is there not a more elegant way to do this? This approach involves my __init__ function header taking up potentially a dozen or more lines if I have many arguments with defaults (which it may, apologies if that was unclear). Further, after spending all of those lines providing defaults, I have to then spend a similarly long number of lines doing what is obviously conveyed in my function header (that self.kwarg1 = kwarg1 and so on). Perhaps I am in the minority here, but it feels not very pythonic, and that there ought to be a less verbose approach.

Comment: @Phoenix i think you should focus on the actual problem at hand instead of getting philosophical about this. The correct solution for you will arise as you add more code and adapt this part to fit your needs. As long as it is readable and tested, any implementation will work.

Comment: @Phoenix It's not always un-pythonic to have lots of arguments. For instance, check out [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). Sometimes you need them, sometimes you don't. However, your code is a bit too hypothetical to give a really good sense of the problem you are trying to solve and whether or not you are on the right path

Comment: @Taras That is good advice thank you I appreciate it

Comment: @C.Nivs that makes sense thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution:

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self, pos1, pos2, **kwargs):
        self.pos1 = pos1
        self.pos2 = pos2
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if key not in self.__dict__:
                self.__dict__[key] = value
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"{key} already exists in Solution")
```

You will need to be careful not to overwrite methods or existing variables in the class so I made it throw an exception in case you are trying to do that.

Example usage:

```
>>> solution = Solution(1, 2, kwarg1=1, kwarg2=2, kwarg3=3, kwarg4=4)
>>> print(solution.__dict__)
{'pos1': 1, 'pos2': 2, 'kwarg1': 1, 'kwarg2': 2, 'kwarg3': 3, 'kwarg4': 4}
>>> solution.kwarg4
4
```

Comment: In this approach how would I handle setting variables to their default values when kwargs does not specify a value for them?

Comment: @Phoenix C.Nivs gave the answer below